# Getting Facebook Page Posts

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've written a bit of JavaScript that will fetch all of the posts on a Facebook Page. The URL with which I do that is this:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/cocacola/feed?limit=5&callback=facebookResponse
```

and this worked fine and dandy, right up until last week sometime, when I started seeing oauth errors.

I've searched for an hour or so on Stack, and seen plenty of other people are trying to do this, - but none have been asked after all of my requests to FB started returning these oauth errors.

It really doesn't make sense, - I'm trying to access publicly available data from company pages. I can still do so without oauth (albeit in a limited fashion) via RSS.

Anyhow, I'm hoping someone can clue me in as to how to get this PUBLICLY AVAILABLE information without having to go through the rigmarole of getting an application ID, an authorization token, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [<strike>recent</strike> not-so-recent change](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2011/05/27/platform-updates--operation-developer-love/), but you now need an access token to access `/feed` and `/posts`. Annoying, but at least it's navigable.

Edit: updated the link, which has broken in the many years since this post was relevant. Here's the relevant text from that post for future posterity:

> **Breaking change: Graph API `PROFILE_ID/feed` and `PROFILE_ID/posts` requires access_token**
>
> The Graph API `PROFILE_ID/feed/` for a Page, Application, User or Group and `PROFILE_ID/posts` for a Page or User will now require a vaild [sic] access_token to access the wall or posts of the corresponding object (where previously no access_token was required). This will also affect direct FQL queries to the stream table, when querying for posts on a wall.
>
> You will need to pass a valid app or user access_token to access this functionality. Please update your code if you are calling this API without an access token. This change will go live a week from today - Friday(June 3rd). We have updated the Roadmap to reflect this change.
>
> Moving forward, you should always pass a valid app or user access_token with all API requests.

Comment: Thanks Jimmy - that was the first actual documentation of the change I've seen. It mentions that I 'need to pass a valid app or user access_token to access this functionality.' Does this mean I can somehow use my app information to gain access or do I still need an access token? As I am querying pages, not people, how would I get an access token?

This is frustrating because I'm basically aggregating 7 facebook pages from a family of companies into one feed.

Comment: I've faced this at my job recently too - what we did was get and store an `offline_access` token for a user at our office, and we just use that token for all the requests we need to do (which isn't very many, relatively speaking). You could get a bunch of tokens and rotate through them if you need to, as well, so you never run out. Be aware that `offline_access` tokens expire if you change your password or you have to reset your account.

Comment: You're kidding, the token doesn't need to be for the specific user whose feed you're requesting? Wow. I thought this was ridiculous before, but that takes the cake. That sounds much more feasible though. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @JimmySawczuk You link is broken, please fix it.

Comment: @Jonco98 updated, but this post is over 3 years old and shouldn't be assumed to be valid today.