# What is the simplest way, using JavaScript, of fetching the latest post from a public Facebook page?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to fetch the text of the latest Facebook post from a client's public Facebook page.

Am I being dense, or is this *ludicrously* difficult?

From what I understand, I need to create an app, use the app ID and the secret to generate an access key... but the access key is only temporary, so I have to do something to create a permanent access key... which itself is not guaranteed to be permanent, and which anyone viewing my JavaScript code could copy anyway. It all seems so incredibly convoluted!

I don't want to have to create a dummy Facebook application, then go through the hassle of a full scale implementation simply to grab text which is publicly available to anyone with a web browser.

The [same argument](https://twittercommunity.com/t/how-would-i-pull-20-latest-statuses-from-user-timeline-with-api-1-1-without-oauth/10303/33) was made for Twitter auth and resulted in the development of the wonderful [TwitterFetcher](http://jasonmayes.com/projects/twitterApi/).

So, is there a very simple way I can grab the text of the latest public post from a public Facebook page?

Comment: What does the docs say?

Comment: The docs are incredibly convoluted. From the little coherent information I've been able to gleam, I understand you're meant to create a Facebook app (despite having no use for one), then obtain an access token, which apparently [requires a log in](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/expiration-and-extension). So now we're meant to ask visitors to log in to Facebook to read *our* public posts?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that there is no public feed functionality as there was several years ago in older API versions. Every request needs an access token, even requests for totally public resources. This means that you do need to [set up a Facebook app](https://developers.facebook.com/apps), even if it's a usless one.

Once you have the app's ID and secret, you can make graph requests, passing `appid|secret` as the `access_token` parameter instead of actually getting an access token.

This should only be done server-side, because client-side it will publish your secret.

So to answer my own question, the below will return a JSON object with the latest post's data, without the hassle of generating access tokens:

`https://graph.facebook.com/[your_username]/feed?access_token=[your_app_id]|[your_secret]&limit=1`

Note that the app_id and secret don't have to be generated by the same user whose public profile you're trying to access. So the following will also work to fetch Coca Cola's latest post:

`https://graph.facebook.com/cocacola/feed?access_token=[your_app_id]|[your_secret]&limit=1`

Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6528113/getting-facebook-page-posts?rq=1).

Answer (score 0):

You have two options.

First: You may use Facebooks Page Plugin [(Docu)](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin/)

Second: You could implement the logic server side to fetch the post. This can be done without additional user token, due to the privacy of the post (public).
[(Docu)](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#apptokens)

Comment: Thank you; I discovered the second way shortly after posting my question. The first option isn't suitable because it embeds an entire feed; I just wanted the actual text of the latest post/status update.